# Grouping 2 Tables without join on in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join, union-all

This might sound confusing but here is what I am trying to achieve... I have two tables with some common columns that I would like to group them into one view... (I dont Have any unique COLUMN)

Table 1:

```
PatientID  Name     Grade x     Grade Y    Grade Z     Grade V
-----------------------------------------------------------------
1          Mohamed      A         C           A            E
2          John         W         S           A            A
1          Mohamed      T         X           A            W
3          TOM          A         X           Y            E
3          TOM          R         R           T            W
```

Table 3:

```
PatientID  Name     Score 1     Score 2    Score 3     Score 4
-----------------------------------------------------------------
1          Mohamed      1         1           4            1
3          TOM          2         2           4            8
1          Mohamed      4         X           8            3
3          TOM          2         X           6            4
3          TOM          4         R           9            9
```

**Output:**

```
PatientID  Name     Score 1     Score 2    Score 3     Score 4     Grade x     Grade Y    Grade Z     Grade V
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1          Mohamed      1         1           4            1          Null       Null       Null         Null
3          TOM          2         2           4            8          Null       Null       Null         Null
1          Mohamed      4         X           8            3          Null       Null       Null         Null
3          TOM          2         X           6            4          Null       Null       Null         Null
3          TOM          4         R           9            9          Null       Null       Null         Null
1          Mohamed      Null      Null        Null         Null       A          C           A            E
2          John         Null      Null        Null         Null       W          S           A            A
1          Mohamed      Null      Null        Null         Null       T          X           A            W
3          TOM          Null      Null        Null         Null       A          X           Y            E
3          TOM          Null      Null        Null         Null       R          R           T            W
```

Comment: The answer is the correct answer for the output you requested, but I can't figure out why on earth you would want such a result.

Comment: Why cant we use **JOIN**. Imagine a table with 30 columns, it will not look good with **NULL as column name**

Answer (score 4):

Use [**UNION / UNION ALL**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/union.html) to fetch all records from both tables.

Try this:

```
SELECT PatientID, Name, 
       NULL AS Score1, NULL AS Score2, NULL AS Score3, NULL AS Score4, 
       GradeX, GradeY, GradeZ, GradeV 
FROM table1 
UNION ALL 
SELECT PatientID, Name, 
       Score1, Score2, Score3, Score4, 
       NULL AS GradeX, NULL AS GradeY, NULL AS GradeZ, NULL AS GradeV 
FROM table3;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select table1.*,table3.Score1, table3.Score2, table3.Score3, table3.Score4 from table1 left join table3 on table1.PatientID  =table3.PatientID  
union
select table1.*,table3.Score1, table3.Score2, table3.Score3, table3.Score4 from table3 left join table1 on table1.PatientID  =table3.PatientID ;
```